# Simple way of removing an array key based on its value

Tags: php, arrays

```
$fields = array('timbo', '22', 'norway');
```

How could I unset the array key for norway based on it's value alone?

Comment: array_search() returns the key

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
array_diff($fields, array('norway'))
```

http://php.net/array_diff

Answer (score 1):

```
$key = array_search( 'norway', $fields ); 
if ($key !== FALSE) {
    unset($fields[$key]); // remove 
}
```

Comment: `array_search` will never return `null`...

Comment: true, i was going overboard on that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [array_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) to get the index. `array_search` will exit after the first match.

```
$index = array_search('norway', $fields);
if($index !== FALSE)
    unset($fields[$index]);
```